# Matrix operations matlab to move values around

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

I have a matrix that I'd like to create a new ordering of, for example,

```
vals = [1 2; 3 4]
```

I also have two matrices, new_x and new_y such that `new_x(a,b) = j` and `new_x(a,b) = k` means that I want the value at vals (a,b) to be mapped to new_vals(j,k).

For example, given

```
new_x = [1 2; 2 1]
new_y = [2 2; 1 1]
```

I'd want 
    new_vals = [4 3; 1 2]

I understand that I could just write two for loops to build the new array, but matlab is notoriously good at providing operations on entire matricies.  My question is, how would I build new_vals without the for loops?

Comment: From you description I don't get the output `new_vals`, could you explain it step-by-step or add the for loop-implementation?

Comment: @Daniel I think the linear indices being calculated from `new_x` and `new_y` are to be traced back to the linear indices going from `1 to numel(vals)`. It's sort of like mapping back, if I got it right.

Comment: @Daniel .. or tracing back to a sorted version of `1 to numel(vals)` it seems.

Comment: @Divakar: Further trying to reproduce the result I found two ways to interpret the data, both resulting in the expected output. I'll wait for Someone_Else to either accept your answer or comment on it.

Comment: Divakar's interpretation sounds correct; I'm looking at his response now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you are trying to get a matrix that when indexed with `new_x` and `new_y` would give us `vals`, i.e. -

`output(new_x(1,1),new_y(1,1))` must be equal to `vals(1,1)`,

`output(new_x(1,2),new_y(1,2))` must be equal to `vals(1,2)` and so on.

We will try to verify this later on. For now, here's one solution using `linear indexing` -

```
nrows = size(vals,1);  %// Store number of rows

%// Calculate linear indices
idx = (new_x + (new_y-1)*nrows); 

%// Trace/map back to sorted version of "1:numel(vals)"
[~,traced_back_idx] = sort(idx(:));    

%// Index into vals with traced back linear indices & then reshape & transpose
out = reshape(vals(traced_back_idx),[],nrows).'
```

Here's another and possibly faster way -

```
out = nan(size(vals));
out((new_x + (new_y-1)*nrows)) = vals;
out = out.'
```

As discussed earlier for verification, let's index into `out` with `new_x` and `new_y` and that should match up with `vals`. Here's a code to do so -

```
for ii = 1:size(out,1)
    for jj = 1:size(out,2)
        check_back(ii,jj) = out(new_y(ii,jj),new_x(ii,jj));
    end
end
```

Sample runs -

Case #1 (sample from question):

```
vals =
     1     2
     3     4
new_x =
     1     2
     2     1
new_y =
     2     2
     1     1
new_vals =
     4     3
     1     2
out =
     4     3
     1     2
check_back = (must be same as vals)
     1     2
     3     4
```

Case #2:

```
vals =
     1     2     5
     3     4     5
     6     8     3
new_x =
     1     2     3
     3     1     2
     3     2     1
new_y =
     2     2     3
     2     1     1
     1     3     3
out =
     4     5     6
     1     2     3
     3     8     5
check_back = (must be same as vals)
     1     2     5
     3     4     5
     6     8     3
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i see what you are trying to do here. new_x and new_y are just coordinates for the new_val matrix rigth? The problem is tha what you are trying to do only works for vectors, not for matrix, so the only way is to transform the matrix into a vector, reorder the values and then go back to matrix like:

```
vals = [1 ,2; 3, 4];
    A=reshape(vals,1,4); % A is a vector [ 1     3     2     4]
    new_coord=[2,3,4,1];        
    B(new_c)=A;    %B is [4     1     3     2]
    new_val=reshape(B,2,2) %back to matrix
```

Obtainig new_val=[4 3; 1 2]. Also B=A(new_c) is also allowed but with different coordinates, eventhoug is much easy to think  the rigth coordinates in that way.

I am sure there must be a way to include the new_x matrix and transform everything into new_coord